# is it Possible to have multiple versions of angular?

Tags: angular, npm

Is it possible to have multiple versions of angular on one project?

Lets say I have the base project on angular 13 but I would like to use an npm package which requires  5=< Angular version < 6.

Could this be achieved? If so, please point me in the right direction.